# How to keep the output order when redirecting both stdout and stderr?

Tags: io-redirection

To describe the issue, I created a simple C program.

```
root@u2004:~# cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("output 1\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "error 1\n");
    printf("output 2\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "error 2\n");
    return 0;
}
root@u2004:~# gcc test.c 
root@u2004:~#
```

When I run it, I got this output:

```
root@u2004:~# ./a.out 
output 1
error 1
output 2
error 2
root@u2004:~#
```

As you can see, the output order in the console is the same as the statements defined in the program. Now I want to redirect both the stderr and the stdout to a single file, and keep the output order. Below is what I've tried:

```
root@u2004:~# ./a.out > out 2>&1
root@u2004:~# cat out
error 1
error 2
output 1
output 2
root@u2004:~# 
root@u2004:~# cat <(./a.out)
error 1
error 2
output 1
output 2
root@u2004:~#
```

As you can see, in both cases, the error messages goes first, and then the normal output. This is not the same order as defined in the program. How to keep the output order when redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of buffering in the program (in the C library). The default behaviour is that output to stdout is line buffered if it goes to a terminal, but fully buffered if it goes to a file. And stderr is always unbuffered by default.

So, since you're printing full lines, line buffering isn't evident, but when redirected to a file, the output that goes to stdout is buffered until a whole block is collected (a few kB), and only actually written then. (You could also try to see what happens if you print partial lines.)

You change the buffering behaviour inside the C program with `setbuf()`/`setvbuf()`, and from the outside with the `stdbuf` tool (and a number of others, look up pipe buffering on the site).

E.g. adding `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` at the start of your program would make stdout unbuffered, and running it with `stdbuf -o0 ./a.out` would also do that. But that will slow the program down.

Note that in your last example, `cat <(./a.out)`, it's only the stdout of the program that goes through `cat`, its stderr goes directly to the terminal. If the two go to different places, through another process, it will cause reordering. You'd need `cat <(./a.out 2>&1)`, or `./a.out 2>&1 | cat` to have them both go through `cat`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the pipe operator `|` only pipe the stdout of its left command, not stderr, right? I don't know that before. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya, yep. It's hard to see with plain `cat`, but e.g. `./a.out | cat -n` would make it evident. You'd only get line numbers on the stdout lines.

Comment: the idea there is that you can do stuff like `tar -c ... | gzip > mydata.tar.gz`, and any errors from `tar` go to the terminal, instead of being compressed and stored with the data (which would probably make the archive broken and useless)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification
!

Comment: @FajelaTajkiya, so, I also wondered a bit what it it is you're printing. It might be relatively common for someone to want to redirect stdout to `/dev/null`, to only get the errors, so it would be nice for the error output to be useful even without the stdout output. Maybe you do have it that way, and the problem with reordering is just the aesthetics. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: haha, I don't have any particular problem to solve. I just found that if I redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file, the output in the file is different from the order in the console, which makes me feel very uncomfortable. You are right, many times only the error message is enough to solve a particular problem.